# Can't print array declared in this.state.arr in react native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array called `this.state.arr`, which I added values to in another function in my app.js file. In the `render()` function I `console.log(this.state.arr)` the array to show and it shows like this:

```
[]
  0: "a"
  1: "b"
  2: "c"
  length: 3
```

However, I want to be able to access the individual elements of each array. I've tried this.state.arr[0], or `const list = this.state.arr.map((e) => {return e;});` I've also tried some other commands to access the insides of the `this.state.arr` array.

But none of those worked. I just kept getting null in the console when I tried to access the inner elements of the array. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: may be you were trying to get value before its populating

Comment: @PranavCBalan That doesn't make sense because I print the array and it already has values. Then I try to access the individual values.

Comment: its showing live content...

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.arr))`

Comment: @PranavCBalan what do you mean?

Comment: @PranavCBalan I did that and I got []

Comment: ya that's it ;)

Comment: @PranavCBalan what do I do? Rip :(

Comment: in chrome console it showing live data....... means whenever you added new data later it will get updated(in the dropdwn list)

Comment: initially `this.state.arr` is an empty array later some values getting added...

Comment: @PranavCBalan I did that and after some time it came up. But I don't want to render these values. I just wanted to capture them. Is there a way to capture the values after they fill the array?

Comment: even when you logged it showing `[]` right? when u clicked that arrow it will show livw content

Comment: @PranavCBalan then how come, when we print just `this.state.arr` we get it working.

Comment: Yeah it showed the `[]` twice then `[a,b,c]`

Comment: may be you need to listen for state change

Comment: @PranavCBalan Can I just wait to check if the length of the JSON stringify is equal to the length of the array?

Comment: I'm not sure how react state works... may be there is an option for listen/watch state change

Comment: @PranavCBalan Okay I'll try something.

Answer (score 0):

Having `null` get returned for your attempts to access items in `this.state.arr` is pretty unusual and makes me think that something else is populating or interfering with your array. When you try to access an item at an index your array that doesn't have a value `undefined` will get returned. `null` is typically used to indicate a value/property/attribute is intentionally being set to blank.
I'd double check where you are setting / accessing the arr. Posting that part of the code may help.